# Error (Xcode): Framework not found TensorFlowLiteC Macos

Tags: flutter, dart, tensorflow, tflite

I am getting an error as stated in the title. There was no such error when using windows. I'm new to macos, can you help with the issue?

dependencies:
flutter:
sdk: flutter
image_picker: ^0.8.6
collection: ^1.16.0
image: ^3.2.2
tflite_flutter: ^0.9.0
tflite_flutter_helper:

pubspe.yaml